# Catching exception thrown by object before code...c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

C# .Net 4.6.1

I am using a 3rd party library. When iterating through its object, my program blows up because the property i'm accessing from the library has thrown an exception.

[image]

So when my program gets to this line of code, the exception is thrown:

```
case CellType.Formula:
{
    cNew.CellFormula = "IFERROR(FF3 / EY3,\"\")";
    cNew.SetCellFormula(cOld.CellFormula); //this is where it blows up
    break;
}
```

When debugging the code, I can see the exception has been thrown. The image above shows this. So, I know something has gone wrong in the library property and what I want to do is capture this error BEFORE hitting the line of code using the property and keep going along with the application.

Is there a way to check an object for exceptions and tell my code to skip over it or do whatever? For example:

```
if (cOld.CellFormula == Exception){
    // do something
}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried try catch?

Comment: Do you not know how to handle exceptions?  Stop what you're doing.  Go get some beginner C# books.

Comment: So you're trying to catch the exception *before* it is thrown? Well, no, that's not possible. You can, of course, structure your code so that it doesn't throw an exception in the first place but if you cannot change the code your only option is to not execute the code that throws the exception. That, or building a time machine out of a Delorean.

Comment: We don't know how this library was built, so we can't answer this. If it's throwing a SerializationException on first use of any property of the object after deserializing (but that's just a guess), then there should be some property indicating success or failure. If not, all that's left is catching the exception.

Comment: If the solution is so simple, why won't you people post it? If you don't know the answer, do not comment. Get a life

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the breaking line

```
cNew.SetCellFormula(cOld.CellFormula);
```

You can put a try catch around it, like so

```
try
{
    cNew.SetCellFormula(cOld.CellFormula);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

this will display a message box with the error text in it

If you are running this as a console application replace

```
MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
```

With

```
Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
```

That will write the message to the screen (remember to take it out in production!)

Comment: I thought about this, but i was seeing if there was another way. The code i have is already in an outer try/catch block, but when it hits that, its a show stopper. I am trying to avoid the show stopper try catch. Thanks